# C: Linux command executed by popen() function not showing results

Tags: c, linux, popen

I have the code below that I refer the thread on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/671461/how-can-i-execute-external-commands-in-c-linux) to use the `popen` function

```
int main(int argc,char *argv[]){    
    FILE* file = popen("ntpdate", "r");
    char buffer[100];
    fscanf(file, "%100s", buffer);
    pclose(file);
    printf("buffer is :%s\n", buffer);
    return 0;
}
```

It outputs:

```
21 Apr 03:03:03 ntpdate[4393]: no server can be used, exiting
buffer is:
```

why `printf` does not output anything? If I use `ls` as a command, then printf outputs the ls output. what am I doing wrong `ntpdate` executing?

If I execute the code below (referring the [webpage](http://www.lainoox.com/how-to-execute-shell-commands-c/))

```
#define COMMAND_LEN 8
#define DATA_SIZE 512

int main(int argc,char *argv[]){


    FILE *pf;
       char command[COMMAND_LEN];
       char data[DATA_SIZE];

       // Execute a process listing
       sprintf(command, "ntpdate");

       // Setup our pipe for reading and execute our command.
       pf = popen(command,"r");

       if(!pf){
         fprintf(stderr, "Could not open pipe for output.\n");
         return;
       }

       // Grab data from process execution
       fgets(data, DATA_SIZE , pf);

       // Print grabbed data to the screen.
       fprintf(stdout, "-%s-\n",data);

       if (pclose(pf) != 0)
           fprintf(stderr," Error: Failed to close command stream \n");

       return 0;
}
```

I get

```
21 Apr 03:15:45 ntpdate[5334]: no servers can be used, exiting
-�2}�����"|�4#|�-
 Error: Failed to close command stream
```

what are wrongs on the codes above?

Comment: If we do `ntpdate 2>/dev/null` we can see that it is using `stderr` so you need to redirect `stderr` to see output

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Since the output is going to `stderr` you need to redirect `stderr` like so:

```
FILE* file = popen("ntpdate 2>&1", "r");
```

this will redirect `stderr` to `stdout` and so you will see output from both. Second issue `fscanf` will stop at the first space so you can replace with `fgets`:

```
fgets(buffer, 100, file);
```

Comment: it outputs only `buffer is :21` here, servers are defined on `/etc/ntp.conf` . if I use `FILE* file = popen("ntpdate 79.99.6.190  2>&1", "r");` that 79.99.6.190  is a ntp server of http://www.pool.ntp.org/ . am I missing something? this is how exactly I use the code http://pastebin.com/8g77zRF0

Comment: Thanks a lot Shafik Yaghmour!

Answer (score 3):

As [Shafik Yaghmour](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1708801/shafik-yaghmour) correctly diagnosed, the output you see from `ntpdate` is written (correctly) to its standard error, which is the same as your programs standard error.

To get the error messages sent down the pipe, use:

```
FILE *file = popen("ntpdate 2>&1", "r");
```

That sends the standard error output from `ntpdate` to the standard output of the command, which is the pipe you're reading from.

Of course, it looks like using `ntpdate` isn't going to work well until you've configured something.