# Connect to OpenVPN programmatically in native C++

Tags: c++, vpn, openvpn

I'd like to start OpenVPN to connect to our OpenVPN server (on Debian) through my aplication in C++. Currently, I'm using key files only (public & private keys), but I need to add username authentication as well. I'm newbie in C++, so I would be grateful if you explain in details and all steps I need to take.

I also need to disconnect the VPN connection before quittig my application, and to avoid communicating when VPN is disconnected (to handle abrupt disconnections). So I also need a mechanism to detect VPN disconnections or to check if the OpenVPN connection is still in place, before sending sensitive data.

Thank you all.

Comment: Just a reminder: I need this app to be in native C++ since I would run it in Linux.

Comment: How did yiu manage updates from openvpn itself, i.e. status updates like authenticating, connected, disconnected, etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved. Used *popen* function/method mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/671461/how-can-i-execute-external-commands-in-c-linux). And of course with this little change in the first line of the main() method:

```
FILE * f = popen( "/etc/init.d/openvpn start", "r" );
```