# Reading the output of a linux command from C

Tags: python, c, linux, error-handling

I have a C program that uses the Linux terminal to run the a python program, but I want to make sure that the python program runs into no errors. If an error message is printed to the terminal after the python program is run, I would like the C program to know.

run.py:

```
g = input(">")

if (g == 0):
    print("error")
    exit(1)
else:
    print("good")
    exit(0)
```

checker.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(void){
    char run[30];
    snprintf(run, 30, "sudo python2.7 run.py");
    // I need to make sure that the next statement is run without errors
    system(run);
```

Comment: This might have a similar solution as C checking for an error in the command "sudo mv nonexistant.x", but I'm not sure how to do that either

Comment: Try [popen](https://stackoverflow.com/q/671461/10077). Or just check the return code of `system()`. Anything other than zero indicates an error.

Comment: you just sent me a link to c++, I am using C.

Comment: Using `popen` is an option, but you could write a C program to use in pipe. Piped programs receive the output of a program on stdin. So you could use: `pyprog | Cprog` from the command line, by doing this the C program will receive all the output of the python program on stdin.

Comment: The code given there will work identically in C.

Comment: What indicates an error message? Output on the stream `stderr`? Any output? A message that starts with `error`, `Error`, `ERROR` or the token `Failure` instead? Or just the return value of the child process? In the latter case, [man system](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html) explains the return values of the call.

Comment: `"sudo python2.7 run.py"` is 21 characters long.

Comment: Just fixed it William

Comment: Erdal, I was going at this issue with both as possibilities for solutions, if I can either read the exit code or the output to the terminal, then I can determine whether or not there was an error, I really just need one to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

-As I said in the comments, instead of using `system` or `popen`, you might use the system pipe command: `|`.

Using the pipe command means redirecting the output (`stdout`) of one program to the input (`stdin`) of another program.

The simple program *(program_that_monitors)*, that I've insert below, rewrites on the console all the output generated by another program *(program_to_monitor)* piped (pipe is `|` ) by it.

from command line:

```
prog_to_monitor | program_that_monitors
```

With this trivial command, to have the `stderr` too, it will be necessary to redirect it to the `stdout`. All very simple:

from command line:

```
prog_to_monitor 2>&1 | program_that_monitors
```

where `2>&1` redirects `stderr` to `stdout` and `|` performs pipelining from program_to_monitor to program_that_monitors

Obviously, instead of the part that rewrites the output coming from *program_to_monitor*, you can insert your control logic.

Here is the very simple C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    char buff[1000];

    while( fgets(buff, 1000, stdin) ) {
        printf(">> ");
        fwrite(buff,1,strlen(buff),stdout);
    }

    return 0;
}
```